Allow assume role from other accounts AWS
I have an AWS batch process deployed on an account A and I have an Airflow deployed on another account B
I would like my Airflow (on account B) to be able to list objects in a bucket of my process deployed on account A, I created a role that should be assumed by my Airflow role to accomplish this task
But it seems to not work, am I missing something
locals {
  trusted_account = "arn:aws:iam::11223344:root"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "new_role" {
  name               = "role_name
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          "AWS" : local.trusted_account
        }
        Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "new_role_policy" {
  name   = "role_policy_name
  role   = aws_iam_role.new_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Action   = [
          "s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:ListBucket"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

I tried creating the role which should be assumed, but it didn't work

Can you elaborate a bit what does it didn't work mean? Did you see any errors? If so, add them to the question. Does the role from the trusted account have the permissions to assume that role?

How does the Airflow Role assume "new_role"?

why not modify the bucket policy from bucket in account A? So you only modify the iam role used in airflow service to allow access to that bucket in account A (in case it doesn't yet have full s3 access). As for the error, it is hard to tell without an error message and/or code to show how you are assuming the role. It might be that the airflow iam role is not allowed to assume.
